# Are twitter user IDs and status IDs disjoint?

Tags: twitter, uniqueidentifier

[Twitter object IDs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/twitter-ids) (*Tweets, Direct Messages, Users, Collections, Lists etc.*) are described as follows:

> These IDs are unique 64-bit unsigned integers, which are based on time, instead of being sequential.

Are they ***guaranteed*** to be disjoint?
IOW, can the same ID denote both a user and a tweet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if they are "disjoint" today, there's no guarantee that they would be tomorrow.  You would be wise to develop your application as though they were NOT disjointed.

In other words, you should assume that it is possible for the same 64-bit integer to be used for users as well as tweets.  This will make your code more resilient to future change.

Comment: That's pretty obvious. Do you have any actual information from Twitter?

Comment: Twitter uses Snowflake (https://github.com/twitter/snowflake), a service that they built for high-availability distributed ID generation.  In their public comments about Snowflake (https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2010/announcing-snowflake.html), Twitter only talks about it in the context of generating IDs for tweets.  I've not found any mention of Snowflake being used for generating IDs for other Twitter objects.  In the absence of any hard information from Twitter, it's a safe assumption that Snowflake is NOT managing user IDs.  We should assume that collisions are possible.